# import os to j2me

Tags: java, python, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to write this code to j2me. Does anyone has any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

```
import os
if os.path.isfile("c:\\python\\myfolder\\test.txt"):
```

Comment: first, attach a c: drive to your mobile device ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Understand what the line does. You can start with the docs to Python's `os` module: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html
2. Read the J2ME docs to find a similar function call.

Answer (score 0):

Something like what is below. Might help.. Just remember the phone needs to support JS175

```
 try {
    fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///locaction_of_file", Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!fconn.exists()) {
       fconn.create();
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```